# How to use PyMongo to connect to a (CA) SSL enabled replica set

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, ssl, pymongo

I use the following code with PyMongo to connect to a replica set (according to the [official documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/high_availability.html)):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient(
            ['1.1.1.1:27017', '2.2.2.2:27017', '3.3.3.3:27017'],
            username="user",
            password="password",
         )
```

I can use the following code to connect to connect to a SSL enabel single MongoDB instance (according to the [official documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/tls.html)):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('example.com',
             ssl=True,
             ssl_certfile='/path/to/client.pem'
         )
```

What is the cleanest way to connect to a (CA) SSL enabled replica set using PyMongo?

> Python version: 3.6,
>   MongoDB version: 3.6,
>   PyMongo version: 3.6.1

Comment: can you simply combine the two options examples you have here? the replica set is indicated by the list of ip:port strings. try adding the SSL flag as well as your certfile flag. replica sets with SSL are not uncommon, I'd think the solution would be straightforward.

Comment: @DylanMoore are you suggesting, ssl_certfile=[], similarly? because there are different *.pem files for each instance.

Comment: Then you will need different client objects.

Comment: Yeah, that's obvious and I don't want to do that because failovers are then needed to be handled manually.

Comment: There is no way to, using one client object, assign different keys to different replica instances. Sometimes it's not about what you want to do but the logic in the class. Why do you have different keys for different replicas in the same set? I would think internal authorization + one key is also obviously what one should do. It's not really in the spirit of a 'replica set' to have different keys.

Comment: I have replica's on different VMs to be specific. Your method makes sense if they were in the same VM, doesn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily, in the case of an Amazon Web Services cluster it would be ideal to use the same key.